# Generate doxygen documentation using Qt project file

Tags: qt, doxygen

How can I tell doxygen to (only) use the files that are in my Qt project file when generating the documentation?

Reason for asking: I'm using a folder structure where a 'common' folder holds files that are used by some (not all) Qt projects I'm working on. Like this:

- projects

  - MyProject

    - common_files
    - SubProject_A
    - SubProject_B

Both SubProject folders will have a Doxyfile and both projects will use some files from the common_files folder.

I know one way to achieve my goal (getting the documentation for just the files used in my project) is to manually add all files in the INPUT setting from the doxygen configuration file. But that would mean I'll have to change the Doxyfile every time I add or delete a file to/from my project. 
Doxygen should be able to filter the files needed for the documentation from the .pro file. But how?

Comment: Will this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507055/excluding-directories-for-doxygen help to filter out directories that don't belong to your project?

Comment: Doxygen doesn't know anything about a .pro file. A thing you could do is to write a small program that interprets the .pro file and adds the result to the Doxyfile (e.g.  by creating a new Doxyfile )