# how to exclude .git from doxygen

Tags: git, doxygen

I am new to Doxygen and recently came across an issue on how to exclude `.git` folder from being searched by Doxygen.

Neither

```
EXCLUDE = .git
```

nor

```
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS = */.git/*
```

work.

This does seem like an ordinary thing, having a git repository with doxyfile for the source code, in the same folder. So am I missing something.

EDIT: `doxygen -x Doxyfile`

```
# Difference with default Doxyfile 1.9.7 (9de8406f02f007519c5d51e67602de9c7ce85c2f)
INPUT                  = /rootfolder
RECURSIVE              = YES
EXCLUDE                = .git
EXCLUDE_PATTERNS       = */.git/*
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES
PREDEFINED             = PYTHON=1
```

EDIT2: Okay so I seem to have figured it out. Problem was in

`EXCLUDE                = .git`

because according to [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507055/excluding-directories-for-doxygen/55383829#55383829) from @VonC's answer

> More precisely, adding a directory to the EXCLUDE directive causes everything in that directory to be searched.

So simply leaving `EXCLUDE` directive to be empty solved the issue.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Which OS are you using? What are you settings in the doxygen configuration file different from the default settings (i.e. `doxygen -x Doxyfile`). Please add this information into your question.

Comment: Information added. @albert

Answer (score 0):

If the `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` (from the [official documentation](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_excl_dir)) somehow does not work, the alternative is to:

- move `.git/` outside the repository
- set the [`GIT_DIR` environment variable](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables#_repository_locations) to that outside path.

---

But first, as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55383829/6309), check if you have set `INPUT` properly, as documented in "[My file with a custom extension is not parsed (properly) (anymore)](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#fac_al)".

> Doxygen only parses files that are specified as input (via the `INPUT` tag) and that match a specified extension (mentioned in `FILE_PATTERNS`)
>
> The list of files is then reduced by excluding files listed as `EXCLUDE` or files that match the patterns set by `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`.

The [OP Marhos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18839354/marhos) confirms that [`EXCLUDE = .git`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude) (which causes the `.git/` folder content to be searched) is the issue.

> The `EXCLUDE` tag can be used to specify files and/or directories that should be excluded from the `INPUT` source files.
> This way you can easily exclude a subdirectory from a directory tree whose root is specified with the INPUT tag.

It is best to leave it empty, and use only [`EXCLUDE_PATTERNS`](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/config.html#cfg_exclude_patterns):

> If the value of the `INPUT` tag contains directories, you can use the `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` tag to specify one or more wildcard patterns to exclude certain files from those directories.

Comment: Without knowing the settings from OP I think the suggestion of moving `.git` and setting the `GIT_DIR` environment variable is not a good suggestion.  I looks a bit like OP starting doxygen in the base directory of the repository  which is never a good idea.

Comment: @albert I agree. I will wait for any update on the original post.

Comment: What is a good practice on where to start the doxygen base directory in.

Comment: @Marhos Did you check your INPUT setting?

Comment: My `INPUT` setting is set to rootfolder, that is (using wsl), `/mnt/d/.../project`. @VonC

Comment: @Marhos Good catch with the `EXCLUDE` configuration. I have edited the answer to include its documentation.