# How ignore standard library includes from dependency graph in Doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

**I am searching for a solution that avoids manual modifications of individual files**.

Given the substantial number of files and the unclear dependency graph, I am in need of a solution that specifically omits standard library includes and exclusively relies on my own includes, such as `../src/employee/Manager.h`. To make it more implementable, I aim for Doxygen to exclude all includes formatted as `#include <...>`.

So far, I've only encountered solutions that involve changing all files.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: Have you tried using either `EXCLUDE_PATTERNS` or `INPUT` from these answers? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507055/excluding-directories-for-doxygen

Comment: I am using Doxyfile version 1.9.7 and attempting to utilize EXCLUDE_PATTERNS or INPUT, but I am encountering issues as it does not seem to workright.